# Is there a method to pass a folder path into a File Upload form in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

System at present uses no models. Takes user selected multi file input, parses information and generates an output. Currently user needs to navigate to correct share drive location before selecting file(s).

Is it possible to pass a folder path (and ideally search string for filename) on windows explorer open using Django form?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the location of the source file that you will upload? if it is, then i think that it is not possible on a file input, the only thing that you can control is the location where to upload the file.

Comment: Yes, it is the location from where the user will select the file for upload

Comment: Base on my experiences,  no that was not possible on web.